# UIImageView create programmatically, then rotate phone?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, rotation

I want to do what I create an image proportionally to appear even when rotate the device. What wrong?

```
class PlakatVC: UIViewController {
    var url:String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil && data != nil) {
                func display_image() {
                    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(data: data!))
                    imageView.frame = self.view.frame
                    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
                    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), display_image)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Portrait:

[image: Portrait]

Landscape:

[image: Landscape]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use auto layout to make the `UIImageView` fill the `view`.

That way, when the device rotates, the image view fills the full width of the device.

At the moment, the image view frame is equal to the view's frame in portrait mode, and when the device in in landscape mode, the image view's frame is not updated. That's why the image is stuck to the left hand side of the screen.

Comment: **thanks it works**
`imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerXAnchor).active = true
                    imageView.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerYAnchor).active = true
                    imageView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.widthAnchor).active = true
                    imageView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.heightAnchor).active = true`